# Using Google Maps API 3.34 Map zooming not worked

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

I have a website that utilized Google Map API and overlays parcel lines provided from an ESRI service. In Google and Firefox the map zoom controls show up just fine.

[Map in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rhTk.jpg)

The highlighting happens on the ESRI tile.

In IE 11 the zoom controls are gone and the map is static (can't zoom or move it).

[Map in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqU53.jpg)

As you can see, the zoom controls are missing and the lines on the tile (yellow lines) don't line up with the base map. This is because the tile is zoomed in but the map isn't. There was an issue like this that was report back in 2014 but was addressed in version 3.16.

Here is my code that builds the map:

```js
///summary
///sets up the map
///Parameters
///-mapDivID string id for the div to place the map
///-coords object with lat and lng properties
///-zoom default zoom of map (I use 13)
///-directions optional object to display directions
function startmap(mapDivID, coords, zoom, directions) {
    var maps = new Array();
    var bounds = new Array();
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService;
    // Get the div to put the map in and check to make sure it's there.
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById(mapDivID);
    if (mapDiv) {
        var options = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: coords,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                postion: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            }
        };
        // we have multiple maps so we need to store them in an array by the divID so we don't overlap one or the other.
        var map = {};
        if (maps.indexOf(mapDivID) < 0) {
            maps[mapDivID] = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
            if (directions) {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

                directionsDisplay.setMap(maps[mapDivID]);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
                var onChangeHandler = function (e) {
                    if (e.which && e.which == 13) {
                        calculateAndDisplayRoute();
                    }
                };
                document.getElementById('txtOrigin').addEventListener('keypress', onChangeHandler);
            }
        } 
        map = maps[mapDivID];

        if (bounds.indexOf(mapDivID) < 0) {
            bounds[mapDivID] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        }

        return map;
    } else {
        // No map div
        console.error(mapDivID + ' not found');
    }
    return map;
}

startmap('map', {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, 13, null);
```

```css
#map { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map">map goes here</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is it requires a key for Google Maps API and I can't put that out there for everyone to view. The code is from the site so I know it works (in Chrome/Firefox). I'm just trying to figure out why the heck it's broken in IE.

Comment: Edit your snippet with the minimal and necessary code needed to reproduce the issue, without your API key (of course). The map should show as snippets from this site are allowed for keyless access to Google Maps API.

Comment: I added a link to maps api but it's giving me a missing key error. Is there another link I need to add to make it work?

Comment: I try to add the Google Maps API key and test your code, it will show me the "maps is not defined" error, where you defined the maps variable? I suggest you could refer to [this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction) to learn how to use Google Map Zoom, according to the document, I create a sample, it works well in IE 11.

Comment: `maps is not defined` you are using this `maps` variable but it is never defined.

Comment: Thanks, I added the definition for the maps array.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
gestureHandling: 'greedy'
```

in place of:

```
zoomControlOptions: {
                postion: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            }
```

in your screen a pan interaction will apear and you can zoom in/out

Comment: Thanks Hello Earth but that only makes it so you can zoom in and out using the scroll wheel without pressing "Ctrl". It is still showing a static map in the background that doesn't respond to zooming. Only the ESRI layer zooms.